# Какие существуют способы вывода exception без показа внутреннего кода (только сообщение) в yii2?)

Tags: php, yii2, исключения

Какие существуют способы вывода exception без показа внутреннего кода (только сообщение) в yii2?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    //some actions
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    print $e->getCode(); // код ошибки
    print $e->getMessage(); // текст ошибки
}
```